# Vagrant Error: File upload source file must exist

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I'm trying to use a vagrant file I received to set up a VM in Ubuntu with virtualbox.

After using the **vagrant up** command I get the following error:

```
File provisioner:
* File upload source file /home/c-server/tools/appDeploy.sh must exist
```

appDeploy.sh does exist in the correct location and looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Update the app server
#
/usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp s3://dev-build-ci-server/deploy.zip /tmp/.
cd /tmp
unzip -o deploy.zip vagrant/tools/deploy.sh
cp -f vagrant/tools/deploy.sh /tmp/.
rm -rf vagrant
chmod +x /tmp/deploy.sh
dos2unix /tmp/deploy.sh
./deploy.sh
rm -rf ./deploy.sh ./deploy.zip
#
sudo /etc/init.d/supervisor stop
sudo /etc/init.d/supervisor start
#
```

Since the script exists in the correct location, I'm assuming it's looking for something else (maybe something that should exist on my local computer). What that is, I am not sure.

I did some research into what the file provisioner is and what it does but I cannot find an answer to get me past this error.

It may very well be important that this vagrant file will work correctly on Windows 10, but I need to get it working on Ubuntu.

Comment: It might be difficult to help you if you just say the file exists and is in the correct location. please provide the Vagrantfile and some information about your directory structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Vagrantfile, check that the filenames are capitalized correctly. Windows isn't case-sensitive but Ubuntu is.

Comment: That was exactly my problem. Thank you.